# javascript regex matches with g flag but not y flag

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm having trouble understanding why this is returning true

```
let str = '\\[\\]\\(\\)\\{\\}\\<\\>';

let reg = new RegExp(/\(/g);
reg.test(str);
```

yet

```
let str = '\\[\\]\\(\\)\\{\\}\\<\\>';

let reg = new RegExp(/\(/y);
reg.test(str);
```

is returning false.

Adding the global flag to the sticky flag doesn't help either.

Comment: Sticky starts at position `0` (reading from `lastIndex` property). There is no `(` left at that position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Adding the global flag to the sticky flag doesn't help either.
```

> A regular expression defined as both sticky and global ignores the
>   global flag.
>
> The "y" flag indicates that it matches only from the index indicated
>   by the lastIndex

You must set the `lastIndex` property of the regex, it defaults to 0, and there isn't any `(` at that index, that's why nothing is matched. The `(` appears at index 5.

```
let str = '\\[\\]\\(\\)\\{\\}\\<\\>';

let reg = /\(/y; // No need for new RegExp

reg.lastIndex = str.indexOf('('); // 5
reg.test(str); // True
```

More on sticky flag [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky):

Answer (score 1):

Sticky flag `y` starts matching at position `0` (reading from `lastIndex` property). There is no `(` left at that position in `str` so your second match try fails.

Sticky flag from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> matches only from the index indicated by the `lastIndex` property of
>   this regular expression in the target string (and does not attempt to
>   match from any later indexes)